# How to validate a JSoup selection string

Tags: java, validation, selector, jsoup

I am working on a program that gives the user the opportunity to define his own selection string. For example in the expression:

```
doc.select("a[href]");
```

The user would have specified the "a[href]" part. Now my question is, how can I check if the passed in string is a valid JSoup selector string? Does anyone know how to validate this?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**approach 1:** Edit the Jsoup source and make the Parser public or implement your own method there

**approach 2:** Parse a simple *dummy* element and catch the exceptions. if one is thrown: query is not valid, else it's ok. Not the best solution but it works.

*Here's an example:*

```
private static final Element dummy = new Element(Tag.valueOf("p"), ""); // used for "testparsing"

// ...

public static boolean isValid(String query)
{
    if( query == null ) // Check for null
        return false;

    try
    {
        Selector.select(query, dummy); // Use the querystring on the dummy - returnvalue is not relevant
    }
    catch( Selector.SelectorParseException | IllegalArgumentException ex ) // these exceptions are thrown if something is not ok
    {
        return false; // If something is not ok, the query is invalid
    }

    return true; // All ok, query is valid
}
```

*Test:*

```
System.out.println(isValid(null)); // not valid
System.out.println(isValid("div.abc")); // valid
System.out.println(isValid("p[")); // not valid
System.out.println(isValid("a:matchesxy")); // not valid
System.out.println(isValid("div > a")); // valid
```

*Testresult:*

```
false
true
false
false
true
```

Comment: I'm currently using a similar approach than the one you suggested, but wanted to search something a bit more efficient. Do you know if, as of 2019, Jsoup made any public method or class to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Check for jsoup sources : you can use the [Selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html). Selector is using QueryParser which is not public, but you can "check" it too.

Answer (score 0):

using `QueryParser` will be more reasonable

```java
    try {
        QueryParser.parse(contentSelector);
        return true;
    } catch( Selector.SelectorParseException ex ) {
        return false;
    }
```